# Replace HTML tag if wrapper contains specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace `<fieldset>` into `<div>` if inside the fieldset there is no `input`. I'm going into this direction but have problems to finish it.

```
(function ($) {
    const selector = {
        fieldsetWrapper: '.fieldsetWrapperClass',
        radioWrapper: '.class-for-radio-input'
    };

    class FieldsetReplace {
        constructor(element) {
            this.$fieldsetWrapper = $(element);
            this.$fieldsetWrapper= this.$fieldsetWrapper.find(selector.fieldset);
            this.replaceFieldset();
        }

        replaceFieldset() {
           if (!this.fieldsetWrapper.has("input")) {
                $('fieldset', this).replaceWith(function(){
                    return $("<div />").append($(this).contents());
                });
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: `$('fieldset')` -> `$('fieldset', this)`

Comment: What problems are you having?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Is this bit a typo?  `if this.$fieldsetWrapper(:not(:has(input)))`?  `if (!this.fieldsetWrapper.has("input"))`

Comment: @freedomn-m I stuck in this last part `replaceFieldset()`. I have problems to correctly write this part `:not(:has...` . I need help in this. I'm opened also on other solutions.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, thank you. That's first part which i needed. Second is... that this replace inside doesn't work.

Comment: You might like to try `.wrap` then `.unwrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your provided code, the line with `$('fieldset', this)` passes your `FieldsetReplace` instance to jQuery and it's not going to know what to do with that. You also seem to be missing a `selector.fieldset` value, but I'm thinking that was probably just a typo in your code snippet.

I've simplified your code down to the part that specifically pertains to your question in the snippet below. It seems like you're just having a rough time understanding the `this` keyword in JavaScript. In jQuery methods, `this` usually represents a single element in the jQuery object. But, outside of those, it operates very differently.

For more information about `this`, feel free to ask in a comment or see MDN's documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```js
const replaceFieldsetsWithoutInput = function (elementOrSelector) {
    const $fieldsets = $(elementOrSelector).find('fieldset:not(:has(input))')
    $fieldsets.replaceWith(function() {
     return $('<div />').append($(this).contents())
    })
}

replaceFieldsetsWithoutInput('.js-fieldset-wrapper')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="js-fieldset-wrapper">

  <!-- Unaffected - has an input -->
  <fieldset>
    <input value="test 1" />
  </fieldset>

  <!-- Should be replaced with a <div> -->
  <fieldset>Test 2</fieldset>

  <!-- Should also be replaced with a <div>, different contents -->
  <fieldset>Test 3</fieldset>

</div>
```

Comment: @Jakub If you want further help, I need more information than that. The snippet works exactly as I understood your problem - it replaces `<fieldset>` elements without an `<input>` descendant. Did I misunderstand what you're trying to do?

Comment: i check it by running this code snippet and also by pasting into my environment. Your code didn't worked. It didn't replace fieldset  without `input` descendant.

Comment: Interesting. I run it and it works fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: I checked in FF.

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry but I'm not sure what's wrong. I check in Firefox and it works just fine. :/

Comment: Ah... sorry. My mistake. You're right. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

## DOM Methods and Properties

The following demo uses the following:

> - **[.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)** and **[.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)**
> - **[.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**
> - **[.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)**
> - **[.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)**
> - **[.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)**
> - **[.insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)**
> - **[Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**
> - **[.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)**
> - **[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)**
> - **[.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)**
> - **[.removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)**

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Collect all <fieldset>s into a NodeList
var sets = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset');

// For each <fieldset>...
/* 
if a <fieldset> does NOT have an <input>...
get <fieldset>'s parent...
create a <div> and...
insert <div> before <fieldset>.
Get the children tags of <fieldset> and into an array and...
iterate the children tags of <fieldset> then...
append the tags to the <div>.
Remove <fieldset>
*/
sets.forEach((set) => {
  if (!set.contains(set.querySelector('input'))) {
    var parent = set.parentNode;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    set.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', div);
    var content = Array.from(set.children);
    for (tag of content) {
      div.appendChild(tag);
    }
    parent.removeChild(set);
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <div>Content</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <div>Content</div>
</fieldset>
```